# Updating android app widget manually using a button on the widget

Tags: android, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I have a Android App widget and a button on the widget. I have set the update time period to 30mins but I also want to update the widget whenever I touch the button. here's my code:

```
        RemoteViews remoteV = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetmenu);

        Intent intentSync = new Intent(context, MessMenuWidgetProvider.class);
        PendingIntent pendingSync = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, intentSync,0);
        remoteV.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButtonSync,pendingSync);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(awID, remoteV);
```

I have set the update time to 30 mins so in every 30mins the function onUpdate() is called.
What I want to achieve is to call onUpdate() manually using the button. But it's not happening. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to SO. "It's not working" as a problem statement truly is not specific enough to get any answers. Please consider editing your question so it is more specific.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is extremely easy. Below is the modified code to make the "onUpdate" method of your widget called each time the button is clicked.

```
RemoteViews remoteV = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetmenu);

Intent intentSync = new Intent(context, MessMenuWidgetProvider.class);
intentSync.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE); //You need to specify the action for the intent. Right now that intent is doing nothing for there is no action to be broadcasted.
PendingIntent pendingSync = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, intentSync, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); //You need to specify a proper flag for the intent. Or else the intent will become deleted.
remoteV.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButtonSync,pendingSync);

appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(awID, remoteV);
```

Now each time you click that button, the broadcast `AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE` will be sent to your widget and the method you have inside that class will handle the update. So either the `onUpdate` method is called, or the `onReceive` method is called. Whichever you have specified.

Comment: It's working great but it's calling onReceive not onUpdate. How do I change it to onUpdate? Thanks!!

Comment: `**PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT**` what is this? I have my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40776920/how-to-manually-call-onupdate-from-within-the-widget-itself

Comment: @Si8 remove the asterisks, I have no idea why I put them there... i think it was supposed to add bold style to the text but didn't. But its simply a flag to the pending intent. It just updates the current intent with the new information.

Comment: This should be the same answer to your question you have linked. This is how to initiate the `onUpdate` method or the `onReceive` method of your WidgetProvider.

Comment: When using this `onReceive` is called instead of `onUpdate`.

Comment: You must also do `intentSync.putExtra( AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, new int[] { appWidgetId } );` to get it to call `onUpdate`. If you don't add that extra, it will only call `onReceive` and you'd have to handle it yourself there (and who wants to do that?).

Answer (score 6):

If `MessMenuWidgetProvider` is your `AppWidgetProvider` subclass, your `PendingIntent` will trigger `onReceive()` on it, not `onUpdate()`. You would need to call `setAction()` on the `Intent`, [supplying `ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE), plus fill in [the `EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS` extra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS) with your app widget's ID in a one-argument `int[]`. In other words, you need to set up the `Intent` to be the same as the `Intent` structure that `AppWidgetManager` would use to trigger `onUpdate()` in your `AppWidgetProvider`.

Comment: Please help with my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40776920/how-to-manually-call-onupdate-from-within-the-widget-itself

Answer (score 6):

```
RemoteViews remoteV = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetmenu);

Intent intentSync = new Intent(context, MessMenuWidgetProvider.class);
intentSync.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE); 
PendingIntent pendingSync = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, intentSync, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 
remoteV.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButtonSync,pendingSync);

appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(awID, remoteV);
```

It will call onReceive();
In your onReceive() method just add the following to call onUpdate manually.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
       if(extras!=null) {
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), MessMenuWidgetProvider.class.getName());
        int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);

        onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
       }
}
```

Comment: I am testing out this code... with my code (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40776920/how-to-manually-call-onupdate-from-within-the-widget-itself) I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: It didn't do anything :/

Answer (score 0):

In the onUpdate() code of the App Widget Provider, add the following to the intent to give the widget id:

```
intentSync.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, awID);
```

In the App Widget Configure activity, make sure you get the widget id:

```
int awID = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;

 // Find the widget id from the intent. 
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            awID = extras.getInt(
                    AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,  AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        }

    // If we got intent without the widget id, exit.
    if (awID == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
        finish();
    }
```

For the button listener call the update then use the following code to pass back original widget id:

```
Intent resultValue = new Intent();
resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, awID);
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
```