# How to manually call `onUpdate` from within the widget itself

Tags: java, android, widget

```
public class VWid extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static String WIDGET_UPDATE = "WIDGET_UPDATE";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        if (WIDGET_UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "onReceiver()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this
        // provider
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            int k, p;
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a");

            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            int k = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), k+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent imageview2Intent= new Intent(context, VWid.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent2= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, imageview2Intent,0);

            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imagebuttonrefresh, pendingIntent2); //

            views.setTextViewText(R.id.textview1, "Last Refresh: " + dateFormat.format(new Date()).toString());

            pushWidgetUpdate(context, views);
        }
    }

    public static void pushWidgetUpdate(Context context, RemoteViews remoteViews) {
        ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(context, VWid.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        manager.updateAppWidget(myWidget, remoteViews);
        Log.d("UPDATED", "testing");
    }
}
```

When I first add the widget to my homescreen, `textview1` displays: `Last Refresh: {current date and time}`. It also displays the system volume in a Toast.

Let's say I increase/decrease the system volume, when I hit refresh the `onUpdate()` function should fire showing the updated Toast and also updating the `textview1` text to the new data and time but that's not happening.

How can I modify the code so I can achieve a refresh, in essence calling the `onUpdate()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

 public static final String REFRESH_ACTION = "com.packagename.REFRESH_ACTION";

@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

   if (intent.getAction().equals(WidgetProvider.REFRESH_ACTION)) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            int[] appWidgetIds = extras.getIntArray(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

            if (appWidgetIds != null && appWidgetIds.length > 0) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "REFRESH", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                this.onUpdate(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context), appWidgetIds);
            }
        }
    }

}


@Override
public void onUpdate(final Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;


    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {

        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

        Intent intentServiceCall = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
        intentServiceCall.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);

     //Refresh
        Intent refreshIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);
        refreshIntent.setAction(WidgetProvider.REFRESH_ACTION);
        refreshIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
        intentServiceCall.setData(Uri.parse(intentServiceCall.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, refreshIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ivRefreshWidget, pendingIntent);

  appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], rv);
    }
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}
```

Comment: This is similar to what I ended up doing. Thank you. +1 for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change this section :

```
Intent imageview2Intent= new Intent(context, VWid.class);
imageview2Intent.setAction(WIDGET_UPDATE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent2= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, imageview2Intent,0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imagebuttonrefresh, pendingIntent2); //


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (WIDGET_UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
         pushWidgetUpdate(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have AppWidgetProvider and a BroadcastReceiver to handle button clicks. Where do I add this? Also the button is an image button in the widget itself.